# How to do f string for exec?

Tags: python, django

This is my Django app name SFC
This is its models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import time

color = (
    ('1','果盤'),
    ('3','港灣'),
    ('5','輕快感'),
    ('6','鵝卵石'),
    ('7','調味料'),
    ('8','農收'),
    ('9','開瓶'),
    ('10','潛水'),
)
# The Chinese in the tuple name color is a noun describe the color.
# Create your models here.
class class_site(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField("學校英文縮寫",max_length=10,default='CKJH')
    Class = models.CharField("班級",max_length=5,default='802')
    page_name = models.CharField("網頁名稱",max_length=10,default='八我啊二班')
    color = models.CharField('配色',max_length=8,choices=color,default="6")
    logo = models.ImageField('網站logo',null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.school_name+self.Class+self.page_name
```

and it's another app name WT
This is its models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from SFC.models import class_site

# Create your models here.
for i in class_site.objects.all():
    code=f'''class {i.school_name + i.Class}subject(models.Model):
        subject = models.CharField('科目名',max_length=10)

    class {i.school_name + i.Class}WorkType(models.Model):
        subject = models.ForeignKey({i.school_name + i.Class}subject , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        work_name = models.CharField('功課名稱',max_length=10,default='習作')
        common_name = models.CharField('功課俗名',max_length=10,default='國習')


    class {i.school_name + i.Class}ExamType(models.Model):
        subject = models.ForeignKey({i.school_name + i.Class}subject , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        work_name = models.CharField('考試名稱',max_length=10,default='大卷')
        common_name = models.CharField('功課俗名',max_length=10,default='國卷')
    '''
    exec(code)
```

It send me:

```
    class CKJH802WorkType(models.Model):
                                     ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I tried not to use f string but i tkink it may be work by using f string.

What's wrong with models.py of WT?
The reason I don't use the foreignkey is because the site is for other people to use, It may cause some mistake.
This is website for education and everyone can ask for create his own class website, it will creates a new class website for him. It can lets the person in charge of the class enter the homework daily.If someone makes the mistake , it would influences the website for other class.

Comment: This is an indentation error, correct the line of your code where you have defined Class CKJH802WorkType

Comment: What are you even trying to do?? Making models dynamically? That won't work well and neither is it advisable. Please research a bit on Database Normalization. You don't need to do these weird stuff, Just have these models have an extra foreign key to `class_site`

Comment: Also if your aim is multi-tenancy look at this package https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (You would need to use PostgreSQL) which would be much better than what you try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`textwrap.dedent(text)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) to handle the indentation from the left side.

Your code:

```
code=f'''class {i.school_name + i.Class}subject(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField('科目名',max_length=10)

class {i.school_name + i.Class}WorkType(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey({i.school_name + i.Class}subj
```

is basically this:

```
class ...:
        subject = ...

    class ...:
        subject = ...
```

which is causing the indentation error and should look like this:

```
code=f'''
class {i.school_name + i.Class}subject(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField('科目名',max_length=10)

class {i.school_name + i.Class}WorkType(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey({i.school_name + i.Class}subj
```

or:

```
code=f'''\  # to skip the initial empty first line
class {i.school_name + i.Class}subject(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField('科目名',max_length=10)

class {i.school_name + i.Class}WorkType(models.Model):
    subject = models.ForeignKey({i.school_name + i.Class}subj
```

Also, **if you really need to solve it this way**, try to use [metaclasses](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-metaclasses/) instead of the combination of `exec()` + F-strings as it just asks for an exploitation or a nasty bug. Otherwise, just try to use foreign keys or other, saner approach to DB structure + ORM.

Comment: Thank you to give me this suggest, but the reason I don't use the foreignkey is because the site is for other people to use, It may cause some mistake. This is website for education and everyone can ask for create his own class website, it will creates a new class website for him. It can lets the person in charge of the class enter the homework daily.If someone makes the mistake , it would influences the website for other class.